# MongoDB - How to search a value into nested arrays?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to do a query that searches a value into many sub arrays using MongoDB.
The db schema looks like this :

```
user:
[
{ 
 name: "SomeName",
 dvd: [
     {
       collectionName: "ActionDVDs",
       movies: [ 
       { 
         _id: ObjectId(X),
         mark: 10
       },
       { 
         _id: ObjectId(Y),
         mark: 8
       }
     }  
  ]
}
...
]
```

I know three informations : user.name, dvd.collectioName, movies._id.

For example i am trying to know if there is any user named "SomeName", having a movie with the ObjectId(X) into the dvd collection named "ActionDVDs".

I already tried this query :

```
user.findOne(
{
  $and:  [
    {name: "SomeName"},
    {dvd : {
         $elemeMatch: { name: "ActionDVDs" }
    },
    {movies: {
         $elemMatch: { _id: ObjectId(X) }
    }
  ]
})
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it, you need to nest the check for `movies` inside `dvd`, or it'll match the movie inside any movie collection;

```
db.user.findOne(
    {'name':'SomeName', 
     'dvd': {$elemMatch: {'collectionName':'ActionDVDs', 
                          'movies': {$elemMatch: { '_id': ObjectId('X')}}}}})
```

Answer (score 4):

I think this will give you a clue:

```
user.find({
  name: "SomeName",
  "dvd.name": "ActionDVDs",
  "dvd.movies._id": ObjectId(X)
})
```